# Interpolate 2D Array to single point in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation

I have 3 graphs of an IV curve (monotonic increasing function. consider a positive quadratic function in the 1st quadrant. [Photo attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEi5y.png)) at 3 different temperatures that are not obtained linearly. That is, one is obtained at 25C, one at 125C and one at 150C.

What I want to make is an interpolated 2D array to fill in the other temperatures. My current method to build a meshgrid-type array is as follows:

```
H = 5;
W = 6;
[Wmat,Hmat] = meshgrid(1:W,1:H);
X = [1:W; 1:W];
Y = [ones(1,W); H*ones(1,W)];
Z = [vecsatIE25; vecsatIE125];
img = griddata(X,Y,Z,Wmat,Hmat,'linear')
```

This works to build a 6x6 array, which I can then index one row from, then interpolate from that 1D array.

This is really not what I want to do.

For example, the rows are @ temps = 25C, 50C, 75C, 100C, 125C and 150C. So I must select a temperature of, say, 50C when my temperature is actually 57.5C. Then I can interpolate my I to get my V output. So again for example, my I is 113.2A, and I can actually interpolate a value and get a V for 113.2A.

When I take the attached photo and digitize the plot information, I get an array of points. So my goal is to input any Temperature and any current to get a voltage by interpolation. The type of interpolation is not as important, so long as it produces reasonable values - I do not want nearest neighbor interpolation, linear or something similar is preferred. If it is an option, I will try different kinds of interpolation later (cubic, linear).

I am not sure how I can accomplish this, ideally. The meshgrid array does not need to exist. I simply need the 1 value.

Thank you.

Comment: You need "nearest neighbour" interpolation? You need to make this question more clear though. You talk about I and V as if we knew what they are in your code, but we dont

Comment: Thank you, I have added some more information and a photo for more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, I think what you're looking for is [interp2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com):

Vq = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq) where Vq is the V you want, Xq and Yq are the temperature and current, and X, Y, and V are the input arrays for temperature, current, and voltage.

As an option, you can change method between 'linear', 'nearest', 'cubic', 'makima', and 'spline'

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out. Xq and Yq can be a meshgrid array, or they can be scalars to index a single point. Unfortunately i think I have to griddata the 3 points I do have due to their disjunction, but it is what it is.